# how to delete an element from an array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

in this program, i gather a nickname and an ip address for 50 different nicknames and IP addresses.

the ip address is separated into 4 integers (x.y.z.m) in it's class (which includes the nickname).

this method compares the x and y with the rest and records the nickname into a double string array. but i don't the same local network (same x and y) to be compared later in the loop so i want to delete each of the same x and y. how to do that?

Comment: Could you explain the use of the inner for-loop? Also, what is the type 'IPAddress'?

Comment: Edited and included class IPAddress. and the inner for-loop is acutally useless, thanks for bring it to my attention @Multithreader

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Use descriptive variable names. 2. Use `List`.

Comment: Another suggestion: 3. Initialize your `result` array. (There is a lurking NullPointerException here.)

Comment: how would you initialize 'result'? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @ShacoNotFound404 By creating an array object. Although, you may want to consider using a `List<List<String>>` instead. What is the result of this function? What does the 2D array of String represent?

Comment: BTW: this  `IPAddress test = addr[j];` instead of `IPAddress test = new IPAddress(); test = addr[j];` is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are staticly sized, so you cannot easily remove an element from an array. I strongly suggest that you use a `List` type (such as `ArrayList`).

Comment: how can i make a `List` type out of `addr` which is already of type `IPAddress`?

Comment: @ShacoNotFound404 `addr` is of type `IPAddress[]` which can be replaced by `List<IPAddress>`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can just `null` the positions in the array you want to ignore (and make sure your code skips null entries). However more generally speaking arrays are not the best data structure to use.

I am not entirely sure what you want to do, it sounds like you want a list of all nicknames which have an IP Address in the same /16 network? In that case, I would use a MultiMap and use the prefix as the key. Then you simple need to put all addresses and later on get the collection for each of them.

Guava or Apache Commons Lang have such a structure:

- https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html
- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html